# Bus error caused by multi-threaded application on Apple Silicon M1 max

Tags: c, memory-leaks, openmp, apple-silicon

I am trying to run the following code solving a linear system using the Jacobi algorithm. The goal is to use openMP to accelerate the algorithm. When I run the code with more than one thread I get a bus error.

Here the C - openMP code:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// jacobi.c --- TP2 : resolution d'un systeme lineaire par la methode de jacobi
//
// Auteur          : Jeremie Gaidamour (CNRS/IDRIS) <gaidamou@idris.fr>
// Cr�� le         : Tue Jul 09 17:33:23 2013
// Dern. mod. par  : Jeremie Gaidamour (CNRS/IDRIS) <gaidamou@idris.fr>
// Dern. mod. le   : Mon Aug 26 14:57:55 2013
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#ifdef _OPENMP
#include <omp.h>
#endif // _OPENMP

// Dimension par defaut de la taille des matrices
#ifndef VAL_N
#define VAL_N 1201
#endif
#ifndef VAL_D
#define VAL_D 800
#endif

// Initialisation aleatoire d'un tableau
void random_number(double* array, int size) {
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    // Generation d'un nombre dans l'intervalle [0, 1[
    double r = (double)rand() / (double)(RAND_MAX - 1);
    array[i] = r;
  }
}

int main() {

  int n=VAL_N, diag=VAL_D;
  int i, j, iteration=0;
  double a[n][n];
  double x[n], x_courant[n], b[n];
  double norme;

  struct timeval t_elapsed_0, t_elapsed_1;
  double t_elapsed;

  clock_t t_cpu_0, t_cpu_1;
  double  t_cpu;

#ifdef _OPENMP
  int nb_taches;
#pragma omp parallel
  { nb_taches = omp_get_num_threads(); }
  fprintf(stdout, "\n\n   Execution jacobi en parallele avec %d threads\n", nb_taches);
#endif // _OPENMP

  // Initialisation de la matrice et du second membre
  srand(421); // pour des resultats reproductibles
  random_number(&a[0][0], n*n);
  random_number(&b[0], n);

  // On muscle la diagonale principale de la matrice
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    a[i][i] += diag;
  }

  // Solution initiale
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    x[i] = 1.0;
  }
  printf("double size: %zu bytes\n", sizeof(double));
  printf("Address of a: %p\n", (void*)a);

  // Temps CPU de calcul initial.
  t_cpu_0 = clock();

  // Temps elapsed de reference.
  gettimeofday(&t_elapsed_0, NULL);

  // Resolution par la methode de Jacobi
  while(1) {
    iteration++;

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(runtime)
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
      x_courant[i] = 0;
      for(j=0; j<i; j++) {
          x_courant[i] += a[j][i]*x[j];
      }
      for(j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
          x_courant[i] += a[j][i]*x[j];
      }
      x_courant[i] = (b[i] - x_courant[i])/a[i][i];
    }

    // Test de convergence
    {
      double absmax = 0;
      for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    double curr = fabs(x[i] - x_courant[i]);
    if (curr > absmax)
      absmax = curr;
      }
      norme = absmax / n;
    }
    if( (norme <= DBL_EPSILON) || (iteration >= n) ) break;

    // Copie de x_courant dans x
    memcpy(x, x_courant, n*sizeof(double));
  }

  // Temps elapsed final
  gettimeofday(&t_elapsed_1, NULL);
  t_elapsed = (t_elapsed_1.tv_sec - t_elapsed_0.tv_sec) + (t_elapsed_1.tv_usec - t_elapsed_0.tv_usec) / (double)1000000;

  // Temps CPU de calcul final
  t_cpu_1 = clock();
  t_cpu = (t_cpu_1 - t_cpu_0) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

  // Impression du resultat
  fprintf(stdout, "\n\n"
      "   Taille du systeme   : %5d\n"
      "   Iterations          : %4d\n"
      "   Norme               : %10.3E\n"
      "   Temps elapsed       : %10.3E sec.\n"
      "   Temps CPU           : %10.3E sec.\n",
      n, iteration, norme, t_elapsed, t_cpu
      );

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This code is compiled and run on a Mac Studio with M1 max Apple Silicon with 64 GB of memory.

Here the compilation command line:

```
gcc -Xclang -fopenmp -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include/ -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/lib/ -lomp jacobi.c -o multi
```

The stack size limit must be expanded to at least 16 MB using `ulimit -s 16384`.

Here the execution command line:

```
export OMP_SCHEDULE="STATIC,10" OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
./multi
```

An analysis with lldb shows that the program attempt to access memory that is out of bound :

```
   Execution jacobi en parallele avec 2 threads
double size: 8 bytes
Address of a: 0x16f2fdad0
Process 5813 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16fe00de8)
    frame #0: 0x0000000100003bc8 multi`.omp_outlined._debug__.3(.global_tid.=0x000000016f2f660c, .bound_tid.=0x000000016f2f6608, n=0x000000016fdfef10, vla=1201, x_courant=0x000000016f2f8fb0, j=0x000000016fdfef04, vla=1201, vla=1201, a=0x000000016f2fdad0, vla=1201, x=0x000000016f2fb540, vla=1201, b=0x000000016f2f6a20) at jacobi.c:91:24
   88       for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
   89         x_courant[i] = 0;
   90         for(j=0; j<i; j++) {
-> 91                 x_courant[i] += a[j][i]*x[j];
   92         }
   93         for(j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
   94                 x_courant[i] += a[j][i]*x[j];
(lldb) fr v j
(int &) j = 0x000000016fdfef04 (&j = 1011)
(lldb) fr v i
(int) i = 0
```

In fact, `a` contains 1201x1201 doubles which means that its data are stored for the address  0x16f2fdad0 to the address 0x16fdfedd7 but the program attempted to read `a` at the address 0x16fe00de8. Nonetheless, `i` and `j` are in bounds.

I can't explain this behavior and I'll be happy to consider any lead to address that issue.

Comment: **jacobi.c**, **gcc -Xclang** are you sure **Here the C++ - openMP code:** ?

Comment: what happens if you move the declaration of `int j` to inside of the `#pragma omp parallel` section? In fact, I see no reason to declare i and j outside of the loop statements

Comment: @273K you're right it's C and not C++.

Comment: @AndyG defining j inside the loop solves indeed the problem. I can't figure out why but thanks a lot!

Comment: @CBld read up on variable scoping in OpenMP: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/3.1.0?topic=programs-shared-private-variables-in-parallel-environment

Comment: If you want to avoid this problem in the future, always use `#pragma omp parallel` with the `default(none)` clause and explicitly state which variables you want to be shared and which private, or {first,last}private. Since it has been possible for almost 25 years (since C99) you could/should also declare your variables in their minimal required scope, which would mean (as here) that they'd naturally be `private`.